# My game tends to crash

Tags: technical-issues, the-binding-of-isaac

I play the Binding of Isaac a lot. I'm trying to unlock the D6, so I must beat the womb as ???. But when I get to the loading screen for the womb part 1, the game always crashes. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Does the game only crash in that particular place and with that particular character?

Comment: When you say it crashes, do you mean that it stops responding or that the program actually crashes or displays some Windows crash message? If it stops responding, do you wait before closing the program?

Comment: What @murgatroid99 said, these "not responding" glitches are very common. You basically need to wait a bit and the game will respond again. Don't click in the window so you don't get the Windows "not responding" dialog hoewever. These glitches happen extremely often when entering the womb/utero. See here at the bottom: http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Bugs "The Pink and the White Glitches"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added my previous comment as an answer, because it seems to fit Shadow Zorgons problem:

What @murgatroid99 said, these "not responding" glitches are very common. You basically need to wait a bit and the game will respond again. Don't click in the window so you don't get the Windows "not responding" dialog hoewever. These glitches happen extremely often when entering the womb/utero.

See here at the bottom: http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Bugs "The Pink and the White Glitches"